# How do I upload to S3 server from EC2 with low cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, upload, put

I have 5072,792,622 files every month to upload on s3 server and it's costing me lot of money as we are using PUT request to upload them to s3 server, is there another method  which I can use to upload files to s3. These files cannot be upload as zip, s3 do not support unzip on s3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amazon S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) has several components:

- Storage (per GB per month)
- Requests (GETs and PUTs)
- Data Transfer out to the Internet

Your question refers to the cost of **PUT requests**, which in US regions is charged at `$0.005 per 1,000 requests`.

If you wish to store all of those files as individual objects within Amazon S3, then you would need to pay the PUT charge for each object individually.

If you have 5 billion files every month *(really?)*, then it would be $25,000 per month in PUT requests. (If it's only 500 million files, then it would be $2,500 per month.)

There is no way to avoid this charge, but you might be able to establish a custom pricing agreement with AWS if your monthly expenditure is significant. I don't know what level is "significant", but I'd imagine at least $100,000 per month in Amazon S3 charges.

More to the point, if you are storing that many objects, presumably at some stage you'd like to retrieve those objects. This will incur additional charges - GET requests are charged at `$0.004 per 10,000 requests`. I would highly recommend **combining multiple files into a smaller number of larger files**. This would reduce your Amazon S3 costs and would improve the throughput of data.

While S3 does not natively support Zip decompression, whatever application you use to consume that data could download the Zip files from S3, decompress them and then access the individual files. Zip files also compress data, so your storage costs would be reduced.